# Redux-Form deleting field on CHANGE action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to get hold of a field in my Redux form, and dispatch Redux Form's values CHANGE action on it to set the field's value to empty string (`''`). The field is deeply nested inside the form. The path to the field (called `campus`) in the form looks like this:

`state.form.MY_FORM.values.assets[0].locations[1].location.campus`

Here is the action I am trying to dispatch on this field:

`dispatch(change('MY_FORM', 'state.form.MY_FORM.values.assets[0].locations[1].location.campus', ''))`

`change` here corresponds to Redux-Form's `CHANGE` action (the one used to change field values).

My problem is that Redux Form seems to be trying to delete the `campus` field altogether from the field's state when the action above is dispatched.

The previous state, action, and the next state look like this:

**Previous state**:

`state.form.MY_FORM.values.assets[0].locations[1].location.campus: 'Some Campus'
state.form.MY_FORM.values.assets[0].locations[1].location.building: 'Some Building'`

**action and action.payload**

`action:
    meta:
        field: "assets[0].locations[1].location.campus"
        form: "MY_FORM"
        persistentSubmitErrors: undefined
        touch: undefined
    payload: ""
    type: "@@redux-form/CHANGE"`

**Next state:**

`state.form.MY_FORM.values.assets[0].locations[1].location.building: 'Some Building'`

As you can see, the `campus` field is absent altogether from the next state. Also, the payload of the CHANGE action is `""`, so I am not sure why this is trying to do anything besides just update the value of the field like it should.

Is there a known Redux Form bug that would try to get rid of a field if the value of the field is set to an empty string? If not, any other suggestions on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at [reducer implementation](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/8768da62a5b4743c89467f8184d4e34e937ae41f/src/createReducer.js#L305) of `redux-form` you will find out that reducer checks if the `payload` of `CHANGE` action is an empty string and deletes the **value** of this field form the store:

```
if (initial === undefined && payload === '') {
    result = deleteInWithCleanUp(result, `values.${field}`)
}
```

The thing worth to mention is that the **field itself is not deleted** - you can still find it inside `registeredFields` object inside the state.